# Check for Existing Firebase User from GoogleUser Before Linking Accounts

Tags: flutter, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I employ phone and Google/Apple auth in an app and I require both - phone along with Google or Apple (depending on device).

I have a use case where an an Apple user switches devices to an Android device, logs in via phone auth, and is prompted to Link his Firebase User to Google Auth (presumably the user switched devices or just has this device and uses it).

In this process, I get a `GoogleSignInAccount` `googleUser` just fine, and I can link that account no problem.

However, if that `googleUser` already had a separate Firebase Account, I don't know that, and linking them deletes the original Firebase Account of that `googleUser`.  Perhaps this user phone auth's on his wife's device. We don't want him linking in this case, he'll delete his wife's firebase user.

I want to determine if there is a Firebase Account associated with the `googleUser`, and I don't know how to determine this, short of signing in the user with that google credential. I don't want to do that, because I have a current user logged in, which I'll be linking.

I already check for existing user by email, but with Apple anonymous or any different email, this is insufficient.

How can I check for an existing Firebase User from a `GoogleSignInAccount` object without logging out my current user?